# PHP array change array structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in the following form,

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [3] => hello
            [1] => world
        )
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [3] => Some other stuff
            [1] => Some more stuff 
        )
    [baz] => Array
        (
            [3] => value
        )
)
```

How could I have it on the following form:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (    
            [foo] => hello
            [bar] => Some other stuff           
            [baz] => value
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [foo] => world
            [bar] => Some more stuff  
        )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing this and not succeeded ?

Comment: In the second code block: what is the significance of `[bar][1] => Some more stuff`?

Comment: `[bar][1]` is really not making sense here. In fact, none of these keys are making sense. Please clarify.

Comment: You could accomplish it in about three lines of code, with two nested foreach loops. Did you try this yourself before asking us to do it for you?

Comment: @Josh Darrow: Don't forget to accept the correct answer. Just tick the check mark next to it. If you don't get in the habit now you will be doomed on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array;  //<--- assuming this is the array you are starting with

$new_array = array();  //<--- This is the new array you're building

foreach($array as $i=>$element)
{
    foreach($element as $j=>$sub_element)
    {
        $new_array[$j][$i] = $sub_element; //We are basically inverting the indexes
    }
}
```